# Maven - build just a few modules from a multi model project

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module project where some of them are microservices and the rest are common modules.

- project-microservice

  - commons
  - data-base
  - ...
  - microservice-a
  - microservice-b

Microservice-a and microservice-b have Dockerfiles that build and copy the uber jars to the image. Each microservice has its own image.

At moment the Dockerfiles are building the whole project and just picking the artifact from the microservice module they belong to.

How to make the maven command to build just the microservice, and its dependencies?

If I use *mvn clean install -f microservice-a/pom.xml* it fails on the dependencies (cannot find it)

I feel like it is very basic and I might be missing something, but I was not able to make it work.

Comment: Add `--also-make` flag

Comment: ["`--also-make` - build the specified projects, and any of their dependencies in the reactor"](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `mvn clean install -pl microservice-a -am` to build the `microservice-a` together with its dependencies.